# Using two css files containing same styling properties for different div tags simultaneously

Tags: html, css

Suppose, I have two different style sheets example1.css and example2.css. They contain the following styles:

In example1.css

```
.colorme
{
   background-color:Red;
}
```

In example2.css

```
.colorme
{
   background-color:Green;
}
```

Is there any way to use both of these styles in my html code when needed? For example, if I have two **div** tags then is it possible to use example1.css in firs **div** tag and example2.css in second **div** tag?

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible. Depending on the order you add you files in the HTML the one will override the other if the classes have the same name. You can have a look at the order of precedence in CSS.

Comment: Use different class or use inline css.

Comment: i think this is not possible because when web is loading whatever css file given that will also run one after the other whatever you put in last file that will give result we can use different class instead of same class other wise we can control using nth child concept

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible use li this

```
          <div style="background-color:red; height:100px;"> </div>
          <div style="background-color:Green; height:100px;"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you name the css rules something different like so you can use them to style your two divs then you can combine your two different style rules in a single stylesheet as you can see below the div class="cities1" is the name of the .cities1 {} css rule so anything in that css rule will be applied to the div that has a class = the css rule name

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.cities1 {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.cities2 {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="cities1">
<h2>London</h2>
<p>London is the capital of England.</p>
</div> 

<div class="cities2">
<h2>Paris</h2>
<p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two files, i will suggest you to do this in one file by following way

```js
jQuery("#changeCs").click(function(){
jQuery("#myBodyId").toggleClass('yellowTheme');
});
```

```css
.redTheme .someBloc{
color: red;
}

.yellowTheme .someBloc{
color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myBodyId" class="redTheme">  <!-- Change body class as per your requirement, You can use body tag in your own code instead of DIV-->
<div class="someBloc"> Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit amet </div>

<button id="changeCs"> Change Color Scheme </button> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you import both css stylesheets and they have the same css class the last imported stylesheet will override the previous one. If you want to use explicit the first stylesheet that was imported you can use !important.

!important declarations overrides the cascading nature of CSS and are often considered to be a hack. You should avoid using them for the most part.

Example:

```
.colorme {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

If you want to use both classes I suggest you give them a different class name.